# Greek religion embodies many tensions as presented in these poetic forms(Homeric Epic)?

Tags: meaning

> Educated Greeks absorbed religion not only through cultic worship but also through the Homeric epic poems and later in the tragedies of such playwrights as Aeschylus and Sophocles. *Greek religion embodies many tensions as presented in these poetic forms and sometimes seems to present outright contradictions*. The gods are presented as immortal and noble, to be worshiped and honored, but they are also described as engaging in behavior that seems far from honorable.

Does this second sentence mean that Greek religion, being presented in the Homeric Epic poem, embodies many tensions? And is there any awkwardness in it?

Comment: It is unclear what exactly you are asking. Obviously the meaning of 'embodies many tensions' is: embodies many tensions.

Comment: The passage quoted is not all that well expressed.  But its meaning is clear.  Kim is right that you have not made clear what it is you do not understand or what is awkward about it.  That is not to say the passage is without its faults, starting with the 'Theogony' of Hesiod which expresses what at least Hesiod believed about the gods, unlike Homer's two epics, which are about two human adventures with gods intervening for a variety of reasons (mainly an unexplained favouritism).  A better choice of Homeric Hymns, which, at least are directly religious.  But the question is not about usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that it would be interpreted that 'Greek religion, which is being presented in the Homeric epic poems, embodies many tensions in it' based on the first sentence. It said Greeks absorbed religion... through the Homeric epic poems, saying that Greek religion is presented in the Homeric Epic and cultic worship. So I would say yes to the first question.

However, for me, this whole passage doesn't sound awkward.

Answer (score 0):

No. It means that the Homeric epic poems (and the tragedies of Aeschylus, Sophocles and others) also had aspects of Greek religion, and these were another way for the Greeks to learn about it.